# Inserting from ArrayList to HashMap

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

as my question says I would like to insert my arraylist items into a hashmap.

This is my HashMap.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> unSorted = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

This is my ArrayList.

```
arrayList.add("1");

arrayList.add("2");
```

Adding into Hashmap.

```
unSorted.put(arrayList,50);
```

I am pretty sure I can't add an arraylist like this. I  forgot I've got to iterate the arrayList and insert the values one by one.

How am I going wrong ?

Thank you for your time !

Comment: Haven't you got the answer yourself? :) "I forgot I've got to iterate the arrayList and insert the values one by one."

Comment: you want to put arrayList as key value or as value??

Comment: Hi denis...my problem is dealing with my key type in the hashmap. Can I add an arrayList directly  HashMap<String, Integer> unSorted = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

Comment: Yes, you have your answer in your posted question. Iterate through the arrayList. something like this: unSorted.put(arrayList.get(0),0) ...

Comment: @Vinoth you may add hole arraylist directly but you need to change data-type in HashMap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterate the `ArrayList`.

```
for(String item:arrayList)
 {
  unSorted.put(item,50);
 }
```